# Checking multiple session variables if they are null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I am using the following to check a number of session variables:

```
if(MySession.Current.mpr != null && MySession.Current.mpr1 != null && MySession.Current.mpr2 != null
  && MySession.Current.mpr3 != null && MySession.Current.mip != null && MySession.Current.vr != null)
{
  ....
}
```

It does not work!  I know one of the variables is not null.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you found out which variable is not null while debugging?

Comment: yes, it is MySession.Current.mip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement is written to only go inside the block if all variables are not `null`.  To go inside if one variable is not null, use ors `||` instead of and `&&`:

```
if(MySession.Current.mpr != null || MySession.Current.mpr1 != null || MySession.Current.mpr2 != null
  || MySession.Current.mpr3 != null || MySession.Current.mip != null || MySession.Current.vr != null)
{
  ....
}
```